# In angular, how to use orderBy with ngRepeat on fields that are displayed using filters, changing their actual content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I'm iterating over an array of objects using *ngRepeat*. The objects have a field "*teamId*".
Inside the iteration, I'm displaying the field using a filter like so `{{object.teamId | teamName}}`, where the *teamName* filter takes a teamId and returns an actual team name.

How do I use the `orderBy` filter in the *ngRepeat* to order the array by the team name and not by team id, if the team name isn't a field in the objects, but a result of a filter?

Comment: you don't. You need to pre-process your data so that your object contains a team name attribute so you can sort based on it. A filter just changes the display of the data, it doesn't modify the data, so orderBy is unaware of your changed data.

Comment: Hm, the first thing that comes to mind is to use the filter programmatically in your controller and save the filtered output in a scope variable, and change the ng-repeat to iterate over the filtered list.

Comment: I guess the most efficient way will be preprocessing the array. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You need to pre-process your data so that your object contains a team name attribute so you can sort based on it. A filter just changes the display of the data, it doesn't modify the data, so orderBy is unaware of your changed data.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options" >
   {{ option | teamname }} <!-- filter changes the displayed value, not the data -->
</div>
```

//JS

```
angular.forEach($scope.options, function(index, value){ // or (value, index), I forget
    $scope.options[index] = $filter('teamname',$scope.options, index+1); // (filtername, array, expression) //this is a hack and you can probably get a more efficient way to pass these params
});
```

//JS this might also work

```
$scope.options = $filter('teamname',$scope.options);
```